# how to transfer this code in flutter_bloc V7 to flutter_bloc V8?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

the problem is that I want to transfer this code from bloc 7 to bloc 8 using emit and on<RunLongRunningStreamedEvent  and i know that mapEventtoState no longer exisits

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';    
import 'data/repository/irepository.dart';
import 'home_event.dart';
import 'home_state.dart';
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  IRepository _repository;
  HomeBloc(this._repository) : super(HomeState.initail());
  @override
  HomeState get initialState => HomeState.initail();
  // I want to replace this stream with a new version and change all the bloc 
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
      HomeEvent event,
      ) async* {
    if (event is ClearError) {
      yield state.rebuild((b) => b..error = "");
    }
 
    if (event is GetHomeData) {
      try {
        yield state.rebuild((b) => b
          ..isLoading = true
          ..error = ""
          ..isSucessGet = false
          ..GetDataHome = null);
        final slidersData = await _repository.getHomeData();
        yield state.rebuild((b) => b
          ..isLoading = false
          ..error = ""
          ..isSucessGet = true
          ..GetDataHome.replace(slidersData));
      } catch (e) {
        print('profile Error $e');
        yield state.rebuild((b) => b
          ..isLoading = false
          ..isSucessGet = false
          ..error = "Please check network connection"
          ..GetDataHome = null);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share the full implementation of your `HomeBloc` so this might have a few errors but it should get you pretty close. Basically, you no longer have to manually call `yield`. You just create methods with the relevant event and `Emitter<HomeState>` (or whatever the relevant `State` of your bloc is) as the arguments, and call the method in the `on<YourEvent>` portion of the constructor.

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  IRepository _repository;
  HomeBloc(this._repository) : super(HomeState.initail()) {
    on<ClearError>(_onClearError);
    on<GetHomeData>(_onClearError);
  }

  Future<void> _onClearError(
    ClearError event,
    Emitter<HomeState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.rebuild((b) => b..error = ""));
  }

  Future<void> _onGetHomeData(
    GetHomeData event,
    Emitter<HomeState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      emit(state.rebuild((b) => b
        ..isLoading = true
        ..error = ""
        ..isSucessGet = false
        ..GetDataHome = null));
      final slidersData = await _repository.getHomeData();
      emit(state.rebuild((b) => b
        ..isLoading = false
        ..error = ""
        ..isSucessGet = true
        ..GetDataHome.replace(slidersData)));
    } catch (e) {
      print('profile Error $e');
      emit(state.rebuild((b) => b
        ..isLoading = false
        ..isSucessGet = false
        ..error = "Please check network connection"
        ..GetDataHome = null));
    }
  }
```